# How do I determine the latest firmware version for a Bookeen Odyssey?

Tags: odyssey, bookeen, firmware

When I look at the page for [downloading firmware](http://www.bookeen.com/en/support_download?idPart=2) it displays

> Cybook Odyssey Firmware Update - Version 5.2 (build 1780)

Is that the latest release, I red somewhere about version 5.2 build 1894 also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sync via WiFi you should get version 5.2 build 1894. You can check if you have that version via the <kbd>Settings</kbd> → <kbd>About ...</kbd> menu.

The manual download page might be out of date with the actual version of CybUpdate.bin you download from there, or the download itself might be the 1780.

I have never tried to install that 1780 version as my Bookeen came with build 1894 and has not wanted to upgrade via WiFi (so I assume I have the latest version).

Comment: I used wireless (normally off) to upgrade did function. Thx.